# use javascript variable in html under if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, jinja2

I have a html page, where I am dynamically displaying the list of properties. Next, I count the number of properties displayed in each div.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var numItems = $('.countdiv').length;
        </script>
```

`countdiv` is the name of class for each property. Now in my html page I have a variable `properties_count` having the count of total properties fetched from my database.

I want to compare `numItems` and `properties_count` in `if` statement, like this:

```
{% if(numItems!=properties_count) %}
     # some function to load more properties
```

But the comparison doesn't work. How do I use numItems(javascript variable) in html?

Comment: That's because numItems is a javascript variable

Comment: yeah I know that, that's why I mentioned in the heading, how to use javascript variable in html. Can you explain me how to use numItems variable in html?

Comment: Jquery template may help you with this.

Comment: Jinja is executed (on the server) before javascript (in the browser) so what you want can't be done. You should use Yuv's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could do reverse. You can use django/ jinja2 variable in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numItems = $('.countdiv').length;
    var properties_count = '{{properties_count}}';
    if (numItems != properties_count) {
        //Do you code using javascript 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem friend, I wanted to use javascript variable in html only.